# why does this c++ code run on Dev c++ but not on a website?

Tags: c++, arrays, runtime-error

This code takes input of an array of integers where 1 ≤ a[i] ≤ n (n = size of array), some elements appear twice and others appear once. We have to return the missing numbers.

Input:
[4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1]
Output:
[5,6]

It works totally fine in Dev C++, but when i submit it a website called leetcode, it is giving me the following error

Runtime Error message:

> *Line 924: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h) SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:
>   undefined-behavior
>   /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:933:9*

```
vector<int> findDisappearedNumbers(vector<int>& nums) 
{   
  vector<int> temp;
  const int len = nums.size();
  int j=0;
  //sorted the array
  sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
  //Added non-repetitive numbers into a temp vector
  for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
  {
    if(nums[i]!=nums[i+1])
    {
      temp[j++]=nums[i];
    }
  }
  //cleared nums vector for later use
  nums.erase(nums.begin(), nums.end());
  //added missing numbers in the sequence to both temp and nums vectors
  for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
  {
    if(temp[i]!=i+1)
    {
      temp.insert(temp.begin()+i, i+1);
      nums.insert(nums.end(),i+1);
    }
  } 
  return nums;
}
```

I know this code is inefficient, i have just started with c++, but can someone tell why it doesnt work on the site?

Comment: dev c++ and leetcode use different compilers. according to https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages- you need to use `clang 9`

Comment: @AnthonyKong If the code is correct, it should compile on any standard compliant compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only appears to work fine in Dev C++. As the error message of the other compiler says, you have Undefined Behaviors in your code. Jesper has pointer one.
Another one would be the line:

```
if(nums[i]!=nums[i+1])
```

During the last iteration `i` is equal to `len-1`,  so `nums[i+1]` tries to read `num[len]` which does not exist.
You would need to change the loop to:

```
for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++)
```

---

The second loop is a little harder to fix. You are using `len` as limit but it is an old length of `nums` and you are iterating over `temp`. Additionally, you are modifying `temp` during that. What you need to do, is to check size of `temp` after every iteration and compare `i` to the current number:

```
for(int i=0;i<temp.size();i++)
```

---

As a side note. There are functions to clear a vector / add an element at the end. You can find the full list [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 5):

Your vector `temp` is empty when you do this:

```
temp[j++]=nums[i];
```

So you are accessing elements out of bounds. That's [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and you cannot have any expectations on the result. *Anything* could happen. The compiler has *no* obligations any more once your code contains UB.

Comment: temp.assign(len,0);        so i tried this and it says "Heap buffer overflow"

Comment: @NagasaiPsv If you want to add element at the end of vector, you can just use [push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back). You don't even need to store `j`.